# git new local branch creation then push remote branch(new remote) and then set upstream using JGIT

Tags: java, git, jgit

- I am going to dynamically create local branches(like
  Hotfix_Test1, Hotfix_Test2 each at different time) and push it to remote.

  - These branches should contain the source available in a branch called Release which is another local
  - Release is already pushed to remote from local using git commands
  - git checkout -b Release git push
  - git push --set-upstream origin Release
  - I create a git object and trying the following code to create hotfix branches dynamically

    ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CreateBranchCommand createBranchCommand = null;
    CheckoutCommand checkoutCommand = null;
    Git git = null;
    String releaseVersion = "Test";
    PushCommand pushCommand = null;
    StoredConfig config = null;
    try {
    /* Consider Git object is created */
    git = createGitObject();

    /* Checkout Release branch */
    checkoutCommand = git.checkout();
    checkoutCommand.setName("Release");
    checkoutCommand.call();

    /* Creating Hotfix Branch */
    createBranchCommand = git.branchCreate();
    createBranchCommand.setName("hotfix_" + releaseVersion).call();

    /* Pushing Hotfix Branch to remote
     * note that the hotfix is not present in remote 
     */
    pushCommand = git.push();
    pushCommand.setRemote("origin");
    pushCommand.setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("hotfix_" + releaseVersion + ":hotfix_" + releaseVersion));
    pushCommand.call();

    /* Trying to set upstream for newly created hotfix branch */
    createBranchCommand.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
    createBranchCommand.setStartPoint("origin/" + "hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
    createBranchCommand.setForce(true);
    createBranchCommand.call();
    checkoutCommand.setName("hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
    checkoutCommand.call();

    /* Editing the configuration file in local */
    config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
    config.setString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_BRANCH_SECTION, "hotfix_" + releaseVersion, "remote", "origin");
    config.setString(ConfigConstants.CONFIG_BRANCH_SECTION, "hotfix_" + releaseVersion, "merge",
        "refs/heads/hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
    config.save();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    ```

    when the execution comes to this line
  - 'createBranchCommand.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);'

it is throwing exception

- **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Command org.eclipse.jgit.api.CreateBranchCommand was called in the wrong state**

i dont know wats the mistake. Kindly help with the error.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace to give others the necessary details where exactly it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already called createdBranchCommand:

```
/* Creating Hotfix Branch */
createBranchCommand = git.branchCreate();
createBranchCommand.setName("hotfix_" + releaseVersion).call();
```

then did a push before trying to re-use that branchCreate() command again:

```
/* Trying to set upstream for newly created hotfix branch */
createBranchCommand.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
createBranchCommand.setStartPoint("origin/" + "hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
createBranchCommand.setForce(true);
createBranchCommand.call();
```

Try creating the branch and setting its upstream config in one go, then push to it after:

```
/* Creating Hotfix Branch */
createBranchCommand = git.branchCreate();
createBranchCommand.setName("hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
createBranchCommand.setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
createBranchCommand.setStartPoint("origin/" + "hotfix_" + releaseVersion);
createBranchCommand.setForce(true);
createBranchCommand.call();
```